# Remove "add to favorites" from Firefox Omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, bookmarks

Is there anyway to remove the “Bookmark this page" icon from Firefox's omnibox? I've looked through about:config and I can't locate anything that works.

Ultimately, I'd like to completely disable bookmarking from Firefox and Chrome and use a different bookmark manager altogether. Disabling bookmarking keeps me from accidentally using it.

Raindrop.io in case anyone has any love/hate they'd like to share.

Comment: There is no such thing. Do you mean "Bookmark this page"?

Comment: Correct - post updated.

Comment: Yes, except not in the title...